# Must a continuous function with rational image be constant?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I stuck with one task. I can prove it, but I don't understand, what is wrong with my argument. So I have:

If $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $\textbf{has only rational values}$, must be $f$ constant? The answer is yes and I can prove it. $\textbf{BUT}$ if $f$  is constant, then $f$ also has irrational values. But by assumption $f$ has only rational values. What is wrong with my understanding?

$\textbf{Edit}$ Wrong is, that function must NOT have irrational values. For example $f(x):=2$ has no irrational values. Thank you everybody, who left the comment)

Thank you!

Comment: If $f$ is constant but rational, how does it have irrational values? I'm struggling to understand your question here

Comment: How do you go from “$f$ is constant” to “$f$ also has irrational values”? The constant function $2$ has no irrational value.

Comment: "if $f$  is constant, then $f$ also has irrational values." No. Why do you think this?

Comment: @StephenDonovan I understood my wrong thoughts. I'm so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you too! I understood my mistake)

Comment: @AdamRubinson thank you, I understood it. 10 hours of math, therefore my head doesn;t want to work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You claim that if $f$ is constant, it ought have irrational values. This need not be the case: let $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be defined by $x\mapsto 1$. This function (and any other function obtained by replacing $1$ by *any* rational) is a constant function **not** having any irrational values as image.

---

The proof should go as follows:

We want to prove that if a continuous real valued function $f\colon[ 0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ takes **only** rational values, then $f$ must be constant. By contradiction, asume that $f$ is not constant, then there exist rational values $a\neq b$  taken by $f$. There must be an irrational $c$ with $a<c<b$. By the *intermediate value theorem*, $f$ takes the value $c$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ takes only rational values. We conclude that $f$ must be constant $\square$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=a, f(y)=b$. Because $f$ is continuous in continuous in a bounded interval, by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ takes all values between $a$ and $b$. If $a \neq b$, because irrationals are dense, there is an irrational value between $a$ and $b$. **Contadiction.**

So $a = b$ and since $x,y$ are random, $f$ is constant.